# Stop Auto complete with space bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using Visual studio Code and when entering a new code a space bar triggers insertion of suggested auto complete. (which is the default behaviour).  I still want auto complete just with tab or enter only.  Note I have the C# extension.  When I press a space bar I would like a space.

Is there a way to get this behaviour?

Have looked through all the Settings and see that the Tap is optional but not the space bar.

Comment: this is not default behaviour, using a fresh install i don't get your issue

Answer (score 3):

Go to `file > preferences > keyboard shortcuts` and look for `acceptSelectedSuggestion` to disable this shortcut.